WordPress Plugin translation not working EN To FR
I'm creating a new plugin actually, the plugin is working perfectly, but it's not available yet in the wordpress.org website,
I have an issue with the translation, I will not use wordpress.org for the translation, it's a local translation, so I generated the PO and MO files using POedit, and I followed all the steps here :
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/ from writing a perfect header in the main plugin file till adding php code in the same file in order to load text domain and the MO file,
When I change the wordpress language from English to French, the plugin still with EN language,
What can be the issue ? is it because the plugin is not on the wordpress.org yet ?
Here's my laptop config :

locahost : wampserver
Windows 10
Php version : 8.1

Thanks !!

Here's the solution : I'm talking about my case here, When I added the Text Domain Name to Gettext functions in interface.php file, I used this command line : php add-textdomain.php TextDomainNameOfThePlugin PathToInterfaceFile/interface.php > tdn.php , So I generated tdn.php as you can see in that command line, and constructed my POT, PO and MO files based on this UNUSED NEW FILE, and I forgot to either rename tdn.php to interface.php (and delete the old interface.php) so I can use it, or to copy its content and paste in into interface.php file that didn't contain Text Domain Name in its Gettext functions.
So now, I just copied tdn.php content to interface.php, and the translation works perfectly.
